# SQL Report - Joining two tables with no common columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have created a SQL report for my organization, This report has:

**.rdl file**, (Report Builder)

**.sql file**, (Query behind to grab the data)

**.rml file** (Report Screen)

The sql behind satisfies most of the specifications for the most part, however I need some insight and assistance with moving forward. The report is to display ALL Date Rolls (failed and successful) based off of user inputting a specific date or date range. I have 3 tables that I am pulling the data from to satisfy based off the user specific date (or date range) all the failed rollheaders and successful date rolls that occurred on a specific date:

1. TaskHistory- When a RollHeader Fails, include Message as to why it failed
2. RollDetail- When a  RollHeader succeeds, the Details come from this table
3. RollHeader -The report is pulling all data from this table successfully.

The problem lies in trying to map the data where two tables have nothing in common, **TaskHistory**(where my RollHeader fails are and a message as to why RollHeader failed is included) and displaying these fields on the report. Right now, **RollHeader**(grabbing * the data from this table). The Report is pulling everything from RollHeader, and RollDetail, successfully. However I dont want to display RollDetails unless I have a RollHeader that has NOT FAILED, which it is displaying Rolldetails, but I am stuck as to how to move forward with grabbing those fails out of TaskHistory with my query,successfully.

Here is my **Test case** (for better clarification):

On Report use specific Date parameter. You will only see the successful Date Roll. The Failed Date Roll information is no longer included.

If a Date does not roll on a weekend due to a System Preference option, there will be no RollHeader entry, but the TaskHistory entry for TaskTypeId 20, TaskstatusId -2 will show the RollHeader failure with a message as to why the Date did not roll. We will want to capture this information on the report.

RollHeader failures do not show in the RollHeader table. They would have to be captured from the TaskHistory table. There are no RollDetail entries for a RollHeader that fails.

Here is my **Query**:

```
    DECLARE @DateRoll  INT, 
@Today DateTime,
@DateFrom VARCHAR(20),
@DateThru  VARCHAR(20)

SET @DateRoll= ?DateRoll
SET @Today= (SELECT InputDate FROM Control)
SET @DateFrom= 'DateFrom'
SET @DateThru= 'DateThru'



Select RH.NewDate, RH.RollDate, RH.StartTime AS HdrStartTime, RH.RollHeaderKey,
       RD.Descr, RD.EndTime, RD.RollDetailKey, RD.RollTaskNo, RD.StartTime AS DtlStartTime, TH.TaskStatusName, TH.Message,


CASE 
    WHEN RD.STATUS IS NULL THEN 'No Roll Detail Tasks'
    ELSE RD.Reason 
END AS Reason,



    CASE
    WHEN RD.Status=0 THEN '0-Waiting'
    WHEN RD.Status=1 THEN '1-In-Process'
    WHEN RD.Status=2 THEN '2-Failed'
    WHEN RD.Status=3 THEN '3-Succeeded'             
END AS RollDtlStatus,



    RD.TaskLevel, RD.TaskTime ,
    T.TaskTypeId, T.TaskStatusName,T.Message ,T.TaskSourceKey, T.TaskStatusId

FROM RollHeader RH
LEFT JOIN TaskHistory TH ON TH.TaskTypeId=20 AND TH.TaskStatusId=-2 AND TH.StartTime <= RH.StartTime AND TH.EndTime>= RH.EndTime 
LEFT JOIN RollDetail RD ON RH.RollHeaderKey = RD.RollHeaderKey 
LEFT JOIN TaskHistory T ON T.TaskSourceKey = RD.RollDetailKey 
AND T.TaskTypeId= 21


WHERE RH.RollDate = (CASE WHEN @DateRoll=0 THEN  dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) 
                  WHEN @DateRoll=1 THEN  dateadd(day,datediff(day,2,GETDATE()),0) 
                          ELSE 0 END)



 OR @DateRoll=2 AND ((RH.RollDate>=@DateFrom ) AND (RH.RollDate<=@DateThru ))


ORDER BY RH.RollHeaderKey, RD.tasklevel, RD.RollTaskNo
```

If you see in the query, I have tried mapping the TaskHistory and RollHeader tables (because I want everything out of RollHeader and everything out of Taskhistory where certain conditions are true) based on the small time interval that occurs in both tables,(comparing the start and endtime columns from Taskhistory with the starttime in RollHeader) However when a successful DateRoll happens on the same day, ONLY the successful dateroll is honored and displayed on this report, not even recognizing a rollheader fail that occured in TaskHistory.

**My desired result:**

1.)All of the specified columns from Rollheader table

2.)All of the specified columns from TaskHistory where taskstatusid=-2 and Tasktypeid=20 (Which will capture all Rollheader fails)

3.)All of Rolldetails where RollHeader successfully occurs on the rollheaderkey in the rollheader table

I have honestly tried to be as descriptive as possible when articulating this problem, despite my limited expertise. If anyone could help me gain an alternative or a better approach, I'd be extremely grateful. I have searched around, but I don't see anything helpful or specific to my problem.

All feedback welcomed as I am new to the industry and trying to learn as much as possible.

Thanks

Comment: What is the desired result?   Why are you attempting to link failed RHs to successful ones, when there is no link?  You say "We will want to capture this information on the report.", but what would this look like?

Comment: hi bud you may def want to tag this with 'sql-server' so it shows up with correct tags and attract a lot more members who answer this question type.

Comment: I have, thank you Junketsu!

Comment: Tab Alleman, The desired result is to show successful RH and failed RH despite if they occurred on the same day or not. Essentially I want to: 1. Grab * data from RollHeader 2. Grab * the data from RollDetail (which only should yield results if the Rollheader succeeded) 3. Grab * the data from Taskhistory(Which has my fails that I need to display on the report)